# Unable to upgrade yarn (macOS 10.13.6)

Tags: macos, yarnpkg

I have a mac with yarn 1.10.1 installed (i don't remember how i installed it probably with brew)
And i'm trying to upgrade to the latest version

```
brew upgrade yarn
```

returns: Error: yarn 1.15.2 already installed

```
brew list --versions yarn
```

returns: yarn 1.15.2

```
brew switch yarn 1.15.2
```

returns: Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.15.2
2 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.15.2

```
yarn -v
```

returns: 1.10.1

Comment: What does `which yarn` say?

Comment: /Users/michael/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/yarn

Comment: So that’s not the yarn binary managed by brew, it’s one installed by npm or such which has precedence in your $PATH.

Comment: Ok, so i did the following:
"npm uninstall --global yarn"
and now "which yarn" returns "/Users/michael/.yarn/bin/yarn"

still yarn -v returns 1.10.1
and just to make sure i ran brew upgrade/list and switch again with the same results as before

Comment: It’s *still* a different yarn. Brew’s yarn is somewhere in /usr/local.

Comment: Fixed it !
I deleted "/Users/michael/.yarn"
and removed /Users/michaelb/.yarn/bin from the $PATH variable
and now it works

Comment: deceze, post your comment has the answer so i can accept it